# CSS3 apply background position using background

Tags: css

I try to get all these css styles in to one statement but i am getting some problem with this. Here i have 'background-position' property. How do i write the following one.

```
.tabbing1 a{     
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:left; 
    background-image: url('../images/nbr.png');
}
```

I tried in this way but having some problem,

```
background: url('../images/nbr.png') left no-repeat
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background position can take either one or two values:

```
background-position: <xvalue> <yvalue>
```

OR

```
background-position: <xvalue and yvalue>
```

Where the values can be pixels, percents, key words like `center`, `left`, `right`, `top`, or `bottom`, etc.

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Comment: thanks for u r quick suggestion.. I added '0 4px' instead of 'left' for background-position. its working like a charm.

Comment: @vishnu great!! Would you mind marking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

try put `no-repeat` right after `url`

```
background: url('../images/nbr.png') no-repeat left;
```

When using the shorthand property the order of the property values is:

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

> background-position: value;

1.value can be anything from below:(you can mention in %)

-left top

-left center

-left bottom

-right top

-right center

-right bottom

-center top

center center

center bottom

ex: `background-position: 50px 100px;`